# how to do database mocking or make sqlite run on localhost?

Tags: python, sqlite, unit-testing

Hi I am trying to write python functional tests for our application. It involves several external components and we are mocking them all out.. We have got a better framework for mocking a service, but not for mocking a database yet. 
sqlite is very lite and thought of using them but its a serverless, is there a way I can write some python wrapper to make it a server or I should look at other options like HSQL DB?

Comment: In Python, all database drivers use the same API for their connections; what changes is how you create the connection. Show your code for creating the Oracle connection.

Comment: This is not entirely True - there are differences beyond, see the DB-modules "paramstyle"-property.

That was the reason I mentioned SQLAlchemy, as it abstracts away these nitty gritty details. Other ORMs obviously do the same.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your problem. Why do you care that it's serverless?

My standard technique for this is:

- use SQLAlchemy
- in tests, configure it with sqlite:/// or sqlite:///:memory:

Comment: Thank deets, my application is currently talking to Oracle Server. There is a JDBC config properties, I need to update it to point to a locally running mocked DB. as sqlite is serverless I cant do that

Comment: You seem to not understand either my answer, or the concept of sqlite.

If you configure within SQLAlchemy with a URI like

  postgres://host:port/database

it will connect to a server.

If you configure it with 

  sqlite:///<filename>

it will open a file-database at <filename>.

All the other code will be agnostic.